# How to load a zip file in java servlet and expose as URL

Tags: java, url, servlets, microservices, embedded-jetty

My requirement is loading a zip file from file system in java servlet and expose as URL (without extracting the zip file).

For example, a zip file is located in C:\temp\example.zip. Content of this zip file is

1. example.html and its dependent files
2. one.js
3. two.js.

How to construct URL like "http://localhost:8080/app/example.zip/example.html"? 
Server could be jetty. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

I can even change the server or can use some other approach also to achieve the above solution. As said earlier, the only constraint is "should not be extracted".

Comment: how will anyone know what's inside zip? I mean, how does anyone know that after the example.zip/ should be example.html or one.js or anything else?

Comment: you can not do it if file is not located in server's dir

Comment: Thanks for your reply @borowis. Assume that the name of the file is like example.html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AdeelAhmed. OK. Now i can place the zip file in servers location. That is the not the constraint. Only constraint is i should not extract the zip file to read the html

Comment: You have to extract the file (even if only in memory)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate a URL for each of the entries in the archive, your best bet is to enumerate only the entries, which would *hopefully* only read the ZIP file's directory:

```
    List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();

    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile( file );

    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zip.entries();
    while( entries.hasMoreElements() )
        urls.add( new URL( "http://localhost:8080/app/"
            + file.getName() + "/" + entries.nextElement().getName() ) );

    zip.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by creating another rest service and loop through the Zip Entries and write the particular file content in ServletOutputStream...So this can be accessed through the this rest service. Thanks to all for your suggestions.